# When do we use double quotes for table names in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

A SQL coding challenge provided a database; every table was accessible when passed as a string using double quotes and not when passed as a word as I am normally used to.

This did not work:

```
SELECT * FROM Athletes;
```

Error message: `relation does not exist`.

But this worked and I don't understand why:

```
SELECT * FROM "Athletes";
```

Was this defined during the database creation? Or is this from PostgreSQL?

Comment: [ask] [Help] [mre] [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Comment: [Identifiers and Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in the Postgres manual

Comment: "*Was this defined during the database creation*" - yes, you created the table with double quotes, now you are forced to always use them.